# PHP form submit loads blank page?

Tags: php

I am aware there are a lot of questions on this regarding this issue, but I have looked through them all and none of the solutions seem to fix the issue for me. I have a form that when submitted, posts the data and it is retrieved via `if(isset)`, as far as I know, all the syntax is correct, and the name attributes of the inputs are correct.

When I submit the form, the data in the form gets inserted into a mysql database, which works, the only issue is the blank page. Here is the php code at the top of the page and the relative html code.

PHP

```
<?php
    require('connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $number = $_POST['number'];
      $body = $_POST['message'];

      try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `contact` (`c_name`, `c_email`, `c_number`, `c_body`) VALUES (:name, :email, :num, :body)");
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':num' => $number, ':body' => $body));
        return $stmt;
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
              <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" id="number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message">Message:</label>
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </form>
```

Comment: Your PHP script has no output

Comment: What do you mean? It's an Insert query

Comment: Unless an error occurs, you aren't outputting anything. So of course your page is blank - you didn't put anything into it. What did you expect the response to be, exactly? The `return` line stops your script (although it doesn't do anything with the $stmt variable)

Comment: @JohnConde @ADyson I see what you mean, I added `$stmt->closeCursor();` at the end and now it is working, thank you!

Comment: `$stmt->closeCursor()` will not affect whether your page outputs anything. Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php.  Did you also remove the `return`, by any chance? And what do you mean by "working" - you never said what you expected the page to look like after you'd submitted the form.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I did remove the return, I just wanted the insert to the mysql table to work and for the user to be redirected after clicking submit, to the home page. Which is now what is happening :)

Comment: That's because `return` halts your script (when it's used outside a function). The problem was nothing to do with closeCursor.

Comment: @ADyson I understand now, the return statement was from a block of code i got from the internet. i didn't know it halted the script. Thank you!